# How to use "fit" and "actual size" when printing PDF by Ghostscript command

Tags: pdf, printing, ghostscript

I need to print from a PDF file. But I need to print 'fitting' the page and other times the 'real size' of the document.

Here is my cenario:

Ghostscript version: 9.19
Printer: [PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator)
File: [_ABC.pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/09np8yvkfyowky1/_ABC.pdf?dl=0)
Command line:  `-dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNoCancel=true  -sFONTPATH=C:\Windows\Fonts -dBitsPerPixel=1  -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1  -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dPDFFitPage -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -sOutputFile="\\spool\PDFCreator" "C:\Users\JUNIOR\Desktop\_ABC.pdf"`

When printing via Adobe Reader (ctrl + p) you have these size options:

- Fit
- Actual Size

My guess is that the command `-dPDFFitPage` is the same as the "Fit" command from Adobe Reader.

But when I remove the `-dPDFFitPage` command, the output is not the "actual size" of the document.

There is a command similar to "Actual Size"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDFFitPage fits the requested media size of the PDF page(s) to the actual media size of the printer. If you don't select this then it will be printed 'actual size'. So there are your options.

You don't actually describe your problem accurately. In what way is the output not 'actual size' ?

Note that since you are using the mswinpr2 device, the printer is under the control of the Windows device driver, not Ghostscript, so what you want to achieve may not even be possible.

Comment: I hadn't initially realised (because I came here before reading my mail) that this was originally a different question here. Can we **please** have a nice simple small example PDF file (**NOT** a 300 page book please) which demonstrates your problem ? And a clear explanation of what your expectation is ?

Comment: I´ve uploaded the sample file that I´m using to print. It´s linked at the question. If you use the PDF sample, the printer that I´m using (PDFCreator) and my command you will have my scenario. I wasn´t able to post more than 2 links at question (Stack Overflow limitation). I´d post the results that I expected and the results that I got via GS command. I´ll do it later (when I get home) here by coments. Thanks!

Comment: I picked up the PDF file, ran it through mswinpr2 to a Xerox Phaser 6120 PostScript printer, then took the output  PostScript and converted to a PDF file. This is the equivalent of what you have done (I believe) by using 'PDFCreator' as your printer. The original PDF file has a medi size of 5.83x8.27 inches. Printers, of course, do not generally have infinitely variable paper sizes, so the multiply converted file is set on A4 (8.26x11.69 inches). The printed image is offset to the top of the resulting page(because Windows prints top down), but the actual marks are exactly the same size for me.

Comment: I believe that you got the point. When I remove the `-dPDFFitPage ` command, the image outputs at the top. See the samples:   [From Ghostscript without fit command](https://www.dropbox.com/s/df52auhjlxg96ay/Without%20fit%20command%20from%20GS.pdf?dl=0) X [Actual Size from Adobe](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2eige51d6kw9ojf/ActualSize%20from%20Adobe.pdf?dl=0).   Is there a command to make the printing like 'actual size' of Adobe Reader?

Comment: The positioning of the image is down to Windows, not us, I think. It could probably be altered by changing the mswinpr2 device. The point I was trying to make is that the page is printed 'actual size' as it is, the placement on the media is a different problem. You could try setting the media to A4 and setting -dFIXEDMEDIA but **not** setting -dPDFFitPage. I believe that will produce an A4 sized bitmap (instead of sizing it to the small media of the PDF) and will render the PDF to the bottom left of the media. Its possible it might center it, I don;t remember you would have to try it and see.

Comment: Adding -dFIXEDMEDIA and removing -dPDFFitPage really renders the PDF on the bottom left of the media. :( If those are the only option I think we are done trying to 'fix' it.  You said about changing the mswinpr2 device. How would this approach be like? Just for the record... I´m building an Windows Application (C#) and firing the GhostScript Printing Command from a button.

Comment: You would need to modify the source for the device and then rebuild Ghostscript. Unless you are very comfortable with C programming that's likely to be a lot of work. You could also write some PostScript to do this but at the moment I can't quite figure out how that would work. I think you would need to check setpagdevice, look for a /PageSize key, remove it from the dictionary but use the information to translate the CTM so that the requested media was centred in the actual media. You might be able to fiddle with the PostScript PageSize Policy to achieve this too.